# what happen if has free space in datapage on mssql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Consider that we have a database and inside it, there is a table with a column. This column stores 1000 bytes char data. By convention, we know that every data page stores 8KB of data separated into 3 part (head, data and offset). Meanwhile, I want to store 10 records. let us calculate it.

> first of all 8 KB = 8 * 1014 bytes = 8192 bytes

then the page head section gets `96 bytes` and every record stores `1000 bytes` data in data section and `2 bytes` in offset section. if we calculate

> 96 bytes + 10 * (1000 + 2) bytes = 10116 bytes

But every page is able to store only `8192 bytes`. In this scenery, we need `2 pages`

The first page is able to store only `8 records` which is allocated `8000 bytes`

If we calculate first page data, we can see `8112 bytes (96 bytes + 8 * (1000 bytes + 2 bytes) = 8112 bytes)`

obviously, we can see that in the first page we have `80 bytes (8192 bytes - 8112 bytes = 80 bytes)` of free space.

Now! My question is what about 80 bytes? This free space is remained as free or `SQL Server` will use it after.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is what about 80 bytes. This free space is remainded as free or sql server will use it after.

It'll remain as empty space in that data page until some sort of operation causes it to be reclaimed or used.

One example would be if one of the existing rows in that data page grew bigger than 1,000 bytes to say 1,080 bytes. It'll use that remaining 80 bytes of free space in the data page to accommodate that row growth.

Comment: You are right if type of column is  varchar, nvarchar or something like that. this column is char(1000). that means it doesn't depend on value. Every time it occupies 1000 byte space.

Comment: @MirnamiqAbdullayev I didn't say that the `CHAR(1000)` column grew, rather notice my wording is regarding the row as a whole itself. Assuming there are other columns (as it's unusual for a row to only have a single column). Though regardless that is just a generic example I gave, and this should answer your question.